# Two threads miss value in loop

Tags: java, multithreading, class, static

I have code like this:

```
public class Count extends Thread {
    static IntCell n = new IntCell();

    public void run() {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
            temp = n.getN();
            n.setN(temp + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Count p = new Count();
        p.setName("Watek1");
        Count q = new Count();

        p.start();
        q.start();

        try {
            p.join();
            q.join();  
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println("The value of n is " + n.getN());
    }
}

class IntCell {
    private int n = 0;
    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }
    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
}
```

There are two threads and they add 1 to value of n (in static class). When I run this code, the value of n value is never equal to 400000 but something about that.
Why something like this is happening?

Comment: This code looks like you're causing a race condition deliberately. It's a textbook example. Why would you write this and then ask why it's happening?

Comment: Because you have no mutex (or equivalent mechanism) to prevent race conditions.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen I smell homework :-)

Comment: @sarcan
yes, it's homework ;). I spent a lot of time on it and I still do not understand it, but now it's all clear :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the basic problems of multithreading. Getting a value, incremening it and storing it back is not what is called 'atomic' - that is, multiple operations are required to do this. What happens here is: One thread obtains N at value X, the other thread does so as well. Both threads increment, and store X+1 as new N - although both incremented their local count by one, N was also just incremented by one.

Whether or not this happens and how much N will deviate from the expected value is, for arguments sake, random.

Check out classes like AtomicInteger and read up on things called mutexes.

Comment: We can say that two threads run at the same time, and value of N doesn't have time for change?
for example:
N = 100; 
Thread1 run and change N to 101
and Thread2 run and also get value of N = 100 and change to 101?

Comment: @SzymonBarylak Yes and no. The result is that but it's not that "value of N doesn't have time to change". We can simply say that a cop, namely JVM scheduler, comes and forcefully stops one thread in the middle of its job to give right of way to the other. The first thread doesn't have time to finish what it was doing. Using synchronized or other tricks tells the cop not to grant access to other threads until first has finished job. Hope my metaphora helps

Answer (score 1):

Race condition occurring. See synchronized statement (below) ...

```
public void run() {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
        synchronized(n) {
          temp = n.getN();
          n.setN(temp + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your question is because invocation of the **n.getN()** and **n.setN(temp + 1)** performed by both threads interleaves each other, for example:

```
Thread 1: n.getN() // returns 100
Thread 2: n.getN() // also returns 100
Thread 1: n.setN(temp + 1) // sets 101
Thread 2: n.setN(temp + 1) // also sets 101
```

You need to implement thread synchronization or other method to achieve the intended result.

I recommend you spend some time on Concurrency chapter on Java SE Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html